# Commands to execute functions in C

Tags: c, function, set, command

I'm using the LXLE 14.04 distribution of Linux.
I want to write a C program to read commands, interpret and perform them. I'd like the program to be efficient, and I do not want to use
a linked list.
The commands are operations on sets.
Each set can contain any of the values from 0 through 127 inclusive.
I decided to represent a set as an array of characters, containing 128 bits. 
If bit at position pos is turned on then the number pos is in the set and if the bit at position pos is turned off then the number pos is
not present in the set. For example, if the bit at position 4 is 1, then the number 4 is present in the set, if the bit at position 11 is 1 then the number
11 is present in the set.

The program should read commands and interpret them in a certain way. 
There are a few commands: read_set, print_set, union_set, intersect_set, sub_set and halt.

For example, the command read_set A,1,2,14,-1 in the terminal will cause the reading of values of the list into the specified set in the command.
In this case the specified set in the command is A. The end of the list is represented by -1.  So after writing this command, the set A will contain the elements 1,2,14.

This is what I have so far.
Below is the file set.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char array[16]; /*Takes 128 bits of storage*/
}set;



extern set A , B , C , D , E , F;
```

This is the file main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "set.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

set A , B , C , D , E , F; /*Variable definition*/




   void read_set(set s,char command[])
   {
        int i, number = 0 , pos; 

        char* str_num = strtok(NULL,"A, ");
        unsigned int flag = 1; 
        printf("I am in the function read_set right now\n");

        while(str_num != NULL) /*without str_num != NULL get        segmentation fault*/
       {
            number = atoi(str_num);
            if(number == -1)
                return;
             printf("number%d ",number);
             printf("str_num %c\n",*str_num);
            i = number/8;     /*Array index*/
            pos = number%8;  /*bit position*/
            flag = flag << pos;
            s.array[i] = s.array[i] | flag;

            str_num = strtok(NULL, ", ");

           if(s.array[i] & flag)
               printf("Bit at position %d is turned on\n",pos);
         else
            printf("Bit at position %d is turned off\n",pos);
       flag = 1;
    }

}

void print_set(set s)
{
    unsigned int flag = 1; int in_set = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(s.array[i] != -1)
    {
        if(s.array[i] & flag)
        {
              in_set = s.array[i];
              printf("%d,",in_set );
        }
       i++;
      flag = 1;
   }

}
int main()
{ 
    #define CMD_LENGTH 256

    char command[CMD_LENGTH]; char* letter;
    printf("Please enter a command");
    gets(command);
    letter = strtok(command,"read_set ,");
    switch(*letter)
    {
        case 'A':
        {
           read_set(A,command);
            break;
       }
       case 'B':
       {
            read_set(B,command);
            break;
       }
       case 'C':
       {
         read_set(C,command);
         break;
        }
        case 'D':
        {
          read_set(D,command);
           break;
        }
       case 'E':
       {
           read_set(E,command);
           break;
       }
      case 'F':
      {
           read_set(F,command);
           break;
       }

   }



    return 0;
}
```

Clearly, it is not a good practice to write a bunch of switch statements and using strtok for each command, and repeating the code written in the main function for each command in order to call the different functions. I thought about using a pointer to a generic function, but since each function receives different parameters,
I do not think this is going to work.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

**Update #1:**
Here's the code. I've made some changes to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "set.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

set A , B , C , D , E , F; /*Variable definition*/
set sets[6];
/*Below I want to initialize  sets so that set[0] = A set[1] =    B     etc*/
sets[0].array = A.array;
sets[1].array = B.array;
sets[2].array = C.array;
sets[3].array = D.array;
sets[4].array = E.array;
sets[5].array = F.array;

void read_set(set s,char all_command[])
{
    int i, number = 0 , pos; 

    char* str_num = strtok(NULL,"A, ");
    unsigned int flag = 1; 
    printf("I am in the function read_set right now\n");

while(str_num != NULL) /*without str_num != NULL get segmentation fault*/
{ 
        number = atoi(str_num);
         if(number == -1)
        return;
       printf("number%d ",number);
       printf("str_num %c\n",*str_num);
       i = number/8;     /*Array index*/
       pos = number%8;  /*bit position*/
       flag = flag << pos;
      s.array[i] = s.array[i] | flag;

       str_num = strtok(NULL, ", ");

       if(s.array[i] & flag)
           printf("Bit at position %d is turned on\n",pos);
      else
         printf("Bit at position %d is turned off\n",pos);
       flag = 1;
    }

}


typedef struct 
{
    char *command;
    void (*func)(set,char*);
} entry;

entry chart[] = { {"read_set",&read_set} };

void (*getFunc(char *comm) ) (set,char*)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
       if( strcmp(chart[i].command,comm) == 0)
            return chart[i].func;
   }
   return NULL;
}

int main()
{

   #define PER_CMD 256

    char all_comm[PER_CMD];    void (*ptr_one)(set,char*) = NULL; char* comm; char* letter; 

    while(  (strcmp(all_comm,"halt") != 0 ) & (all_comm != NULL))
    {
        printf("Please enter a command");
        gets(all_comm);
        comm = strtok(all_comm,", ");
        ptr_one = getFunc(comm);
        letter = strtok(NULL,",");
        ptr_one(A,all_comm);
        all_comm[0] = '\0';
        letter[0] = '\0';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following compile error:
main.c:9:8: error: expected ���=���, ���,���, ���;���, ���asm��� or ���**attribute**��� before ���.��� token

What's my mistake? How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot! @Claim Yang

Comment: Can you add a test case too?

Comment: `strtok(command,"read_set ,");` Please read the `strtok` manual again. You are not using it correctly. It does not do a sub string match/search. A more appropriate function for your purposes is [`strstr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr).

Comment: As for your question an arguably better way is to define a command structure that has a command name and function pointer for each command. And then have an array/list of these structures which can be matched in a loop.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been trying to create a structure containing an array of pointers to functions like so
typedef struct 
{
    void(*functions[6])(set,char[]);
}command;
Where each of the array elements contains a function which corresponds to a certain command.I'm not really sure how to get going from here and how that would prevent code repetition. Did I go wrong? Can you explain it in a little more detail?
Thanks!

Comment: I read the manual, but I cannot seem to figure out why I use strtok the wrong way. What's my mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I can add a test case. @user161151

Answer (score -1):

However,in your case, using `switch` is almost the best solution to this.

Another way without `switch` is using a simple way to get an index. Here is a simple solution.

```
set sets[6];
read_set(sets[*letter - 'A'], command);
```

Then if you need to read a command, another array of pointers to functions is needed. Like below:

```
void (*functions[3])(set,char[]);
functions[0] = read_set;
```

And so on.
The point is coverting your `string` to an `int`, so it can be seen as an index of an array.

Then call functions like `functions[string_to_int(string)](set,char[]);`

Comment: The OP has another problem that this answer does not address: "repeating the code written in the main function for each command in order to call the different functions". That is, how to avoid repeating the switch statement to call "print_set, union_set, intersect_set, sub_set and halt".

Comment: Then another array of  pointers to functions is needed. And you also need to convert the commands to indexes. Things are becoming difficult for a beginner..@kaylum

Comment: Whether it is becoming difficult or not is besides the point. An answer should adequately address the issues raised by the question. Suggest you update your answer accordingly.

Comment: As I understand it, sets will hold the characters 'A' through 'F'.

Comment: Yes, but you can change the rule that convert a char to an integer instead of `*letter - 'A'`, and expand the size of `sets`.`@Tree`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still not sure how that would solve the code repetition. I thought about this
for(i=0; i<num_of_functions; i++)
    functions[i];
The problem is that it is the user's choice weather or not a function is called and in the code written func[0] though func[num_of_functions-1] is called either way while executing the program.If I understand it well,since the functions receive different parameters I will need to have more than one array of pointers to functions.Did I go wrong? Can you explain it in more detail? Thanks!

Comment: C++ is not C and a better language would be Python or Ruby. But such recommendations are a bad idea, if OP asks for a particular language. This problem can be solved in C without problems, as show the various  compilers and interpreters written in C.

Comment: For an example:  the command read_set A,1,2,14,-1 in the terminal will be read as 5 elements:com="read_set",target="A",nums[0]='1',nums[1]='2',nums[2]='14'. Then the call should be `functions[string_to_int(com)](A,nums)` @Tree

Comment: I'm just giving suggestions.No wrong code,no misleading. This problem can be solved in C,that's right,but please give a easy solution to a beginner, not simply downvote.Of course i'm not mean to offend@Olaf

Comment: I've been trying to initialize the sets variable, but when I tried  to I got compile error massages. I tried to do something like this:
set sets[6]; 
sets[0] = A; sets[1]=B; sets[2]=C; sets[3]=D; sets[4]=E; sets[5]=F; but I got a compile error massage: expected identifier or ( before [ token.
I also tried to do something like sets[0].array=A.array sets[1]=B.array etc, but I got the same massage as above. 
Where is my mistake and how can I initialize sets so that sets holds the sets A though F?
Thanks! @Claim Yang

Comment: Post your code, or no one can know what exactly happend.

Comment: I appended my code onto my original post beneath the title Update #1, as I am limited in character length. Thank you very much!